# How to assume AWS role from the same AWS role in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm using an IAM role for a glue job that makes some data processing, to accomplish this task I need to assume the role that executes the glue role.

As example, in the following cloudformation template the `IAM::Policy` has permission to query from a Dynamo DB table and to get Objects from an s3 bucket.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources: 

  GlueAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref GlueRole
      PolicyName: glue_access_policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 's3:getObject'
            Resource:
              - 's3_bucket_arn'
          - Effect: Allow 
            Action: 
              - 'dynamodb:DescribeTable'
              - 'dynamodb:Query'
            Resource:
              - 'dynamo_table_arn'

  GlueRole: 
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties: 
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal: 
              Service:
                - 'glue.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

Now, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652440/how-to-assume-an-aws-role-from-another-aws-role) illustrates an example to assume role B from role A, switching roles.

So, I have the question if **is it possible or valid for `GlueRole` to assume `GlueRole` ?**

Answer (score 0):

As there is no limitation for the role to assume itself, and the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html) state the following

> A policy that grants a user permission to assume a role must include a statement with the Allow effect on the following:
>
> - The sts:AssumeRole action
> - The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the role in a Resource element

it is straightforward to add this policy to the `AWS::IAM::Policy` resource on the CloudFormation template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources: 

  GlueAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref GlueRole
      PolicyName: glue_access_policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Resource: !GetAtt GlueRole.Arn

  GlueRole: 
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties: 
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal: 
              Service:
                - 'glue.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
```